# how to sort files by their permissions using ls?

Tags: ls, sort

I have a large number of files and directories in one directory.

I need to sort them in terms of the permissions.

For example

```
drwx------
drwxr-xr-x 
drwxr-x---
```

I am just wondering if we can sort the files and dirs using `ls`?

Comment: `ls -l|sort` will sort by permissions.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`ls` does not directly support sorting by permissions, but you can combine it with the sort command:

```
ls -l | sort
```

You can use the `-k` option to sort to start matching from a specific character, the format is `-k FIELD.CHAR`, the permissions are the first field in the `ls` output. So e.g. `-k 1.2` will start from the second character of the permission string, which will ignore any directory / device / link etc. flag, or `-k 1.5` for sorting by group permissions.

If you don't want the additional output of `ls -l`, you can remove it with awk:

```
 ls -l | sort | awk '{ print $1, $NF}'
```

This will print only the first field (the permissions) and the last one (the filename).

Comment: If you don't want additional output it much easy to use `stat` command `stat -c"%A %n" * | sort`

Answer (score 2):

You can also sort by octal value.

```
for i in *; do stat --format="%a %n" "$i"; done | sort -n
```